# What do I have to remove from the Python3 installation to make it impossible to compile scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a system that will exposed on the Internet. I've done as much as I can do to limit the attack surface, but one important hole remains. The python scripts are only present in their compiled form (.pyc) and the sources (.py) are not present. How can I stop someone transforming their own script into an executable? Are there some parts of python that I can delete so that it will only execute pre-compiled scripts?

Comment: If this is a concern, then you still have many other open attack vectors.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [PYC-only distribution](https://mythreyatechblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/01/first-blog-post/), that installed instead of your regular python package will accomplish the goal.

However the attacker could just bring their own python if they are able to create files on your server.

How about disallowing writing new files in the directory (assuming you're using linux it's `# chmod ugo-w <dirname>`)

EDIT:
Maybe a good solution would be to ditch python interpreter and VM completely on the production machine, compile scripts with [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html), and put execuables created by Nuitka in the write-forbidden directory.

Comment: That's a useful answer, but only relates to the scripts themselves. Effectively it allows you to pre-compile the scripts and remove the original sources. I was wondering if there was a subset of the Python run-time that disallowed compilation from source. If not, I suppose there's always Cython!  
Yes, you're right, but it's a lot of stuff to have to install. I've done my best by running the system with most disks read-only - the only writeable ones are backed by memory. I've also removed most of the shell commands including "mount".

Comment: @Nicole Which part you say allows to pre-compile scripts and remove sources?

Comment: But if someone could introduce a pyc (compiled elsewhere) this pyc-only distribution could execute it?

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to have secure list of file hashes (md5 for instance) and only allowing to execute files whose hash matches the one from the list...